# Find all noncharacteristic curves of the PDE $x_2 \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_1}=x_1 \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Find all non-characteristic initial curves of the PDE given by   $\;\;\;x_2 \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_1}-x_1 \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_2}=0$.

These are the curves that are nowhere tangent to the coefficient vector $(x_2,-x_1)$.

that is, we look for curves $\gamma(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ such that for all $t$ the following system of ODEs is **not** satisfied: $\begin{cases}
\frac{dx_1}{dt}=x_2  \\ 
\frac{dx_2}{dt}=-x_1
\end{cases}$.

By solving this system, we see that this is equivalent to finding all curves $\gamma(t)$ such that for all $t$ there are no constants $a,b$ such that $\gamma(t)=(-a \sin t+b \cos t, a \cos t+b \sin t)$ in a neighborhood of $t$.

The curves of the form $(-a \sin t+b \cos t, a \cos t+b \sin t)$ are the *characteristic curves* of the PDE. Sadly, it seems that finding non-characteristic curves is not equivalent to just finding all curves that are not characteristic, because we require that the curve is at *no point* tangent to $(x_2,-x_1)$. Moreover, even the preceding characterization of characteristic curves seems insufficient; is there a way to eliminate $t$ and relate $x_1,x_2$ directly?

How should I proceed?